# How do I modify the PATH for an ansible task?

Tags: ansible

I installed https://asdf-vm.com/ and my tools (ruby, python, nodejs, etc) on an Ubuntu server using ansible tasks. As a later task, I am trying to run this:

```
- name: Install the latest "tree-sitter-cli" node.js package globally.
  community.general.npm:
    name: tree-sitter-cli
    state: latest
    global: true
```

No matter what I do, I get this error:

```
TASK [nvim : Install the latest "tree-sitter-cli" node.js package globally.] ***********************
fatal: [ansible-test]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to find required
executable \"npm\" in paths:
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin"}
```

I have tried:

- Adding `. "$HOME/.asdf/asdf.sh"` and `export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.asdf/shims` to `$HOME/.bashrc`

  - That didn't work, so I then added `source $HOME/.bashrc` to `.bash_profile` and `.profile`.
- `.zshrc` is my usual config, which has the `asdf` plugin

The only way I have figured out to get around this is to have a task like this, which I do not want to do:

```
- name: Install the latest "tree-sitter-cli" node.js package globally.
  command: zsh -l -c 'npm -g tree-sitter-cli'
```

I think I can also provide an `environment` key specific tasks, but I would rather just have `asdf` and the installed tools available to all tasks. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

I found [this page](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_environment.html#working-with-language-specific-version-managers), which was a really good example of how to handle this. I added this to my playbook and it worked:

```
environment:
  PATH: '{{ ansible_env.PATH }}:{{ ansible_env.HOME }}/.asdf/shims'
```